# Populate empty rows based on values in specific columns

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that contains the customer code, store name, street and city and some other columns. The problem is that some of the columns are blank because some data were copied from elsewhere.
For example:

| Code | Name | Street | Ort | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Shop1 | Felder Str. | 3278 | Herslden |
|  | Shop1 |  |  | Herslden |
| 1211 | ShopX | Walkt Str. | 4414 | Windsheld |
|  | Shop X |  |  | Windsheld |

I want to be able to populate the empty columns based on the "Name1" and "Ort" columns. So for example, if 'Name' is "Shop 1" and City is "Herslden", copy the content of its Code, Street and Ort columns into the ones which are empty. In the end, have something like:

| Code | Name | Street | Ort | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Shop1 | Felder Str. | 3278 | Herslden |
| 1111 | Shop1 | Felder Str. | 3278 | Herslden |
| 1211 | ShopX | Walkt Str. | 4414 | Windsheld |
| 1211 | ShopX | Walkt Str. | 4414 | Windsheld |

I was thinking there should be a way to do this using Excel formula or python. I have thousands of rows and to do them manually might take the whole day.

Comment: Load it into Power Query (available in Excel 2010+); select all the columns and **Fill Down**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty but effective and easy way would be just duplicating the data and copy/paste them as values

[image]

You'll need to copy headers as well. Formula is just `=IF(A2="";A1;A2)`

As I said, it's dirty but easy and works good